# I need to update a Varchar column strings, appending '-H' to the current strings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL 2012.  I have a table with an ID (varchar(16)) and a Direction (smallint).

Basically, I want to take whatever the current ID is and append '-H' where Direction = 1, append a '-V' where Direction = 2 and append a '-A' where Direction = 3.

Example:
ID= string1
Direction = 1

The ID for that row will be updated to 'string1-H'

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` statement like

```
case when Direction = 1 then ID + '-H'
when Direction = 2 then ID + '-V'
else ID + '-A'
end as NEWID
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to go on in your original post, but you could try the following using a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT [ID]
    + CASE [Direction]
        WHEN 1 THEN '-H'
        WHEN 2 THEN '-V'
        WHEN 3 THEN '-A'
        ELSE '' END AS AppendedID
FROM [Table]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select 

    CASE Direction no 
      WHEN 1 THEN string1 + '-H'
      WHEN 2 THEN string1 + '-V' 
      WHEN 3 THEN string1 + '-A' 

    END as string1
    from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

You didn't mention the case when Direction has a value other than 1,2,3, I assumed blank.

```
SELECT ID+ IIF(Direction = 3, '-A', IIF(Direction = 2, '-V', IIF(Direction = 1, '-H', '')) ) as result
```